# Calculate variance of polynomial expression (continuous correlated random variables)

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

I have the following problem: $f_{(X,Y)}(x, y)$ as a PDF of a continuous random variable. I had to calculate the marginal PDF/CDFs, and the means and vars of these ($E(X), E(Y), Var(X), Var(Y)$).

Now I have another random variable $Z = (X-2)^2 + Y$, and I need to calculate $E(Z)$ and $Var(Z)$.

I had no problems with $E(Z)$, but I do have some trouble with $Var(Z)$.
$Var(Z) = Var(X^2 - 2X + 3Y)$. How do I need to proceed from here? Even if $X$ and $Y$ were not correlated, I still wouldn't know how to calculate $Var(X^2)$. (I did google this, but there were many confusing solutions). Is it $E(X^4) - [E(X^2)]^2$?

And if it is, could you still help me figure out how to calculate the whole $Var(X^2 - 2X + 3Y)$ part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula:

$$V(X+Y+Z)=V(X)+V(Y)+V(Z)+2Cov(X,Y)+2Cov(X,Z)+2Cov(Y,Z)$$

and treat $X^2$ as a RV, so

$$V(X^2)=E((X^2)^2)-(E(X^2))^2$$

Comment: thank you for your answer :)

However, I'm still a bit dumb for this. If $Var(X - Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y)−2Cov(X,Y)$, then what would be $Var(X-Y+Z)$ ?

Is it $V(X)+V(Y)+V(Z)-2Cov(X,Y)+2Cov(X,Z)-2Cov(Y,Z)$?

Comment: The minus sign goes with $Y$, so it should be before every term that involves it: $X-Y=X+(-Y)$ and $Cov(aX,bY)=abCov(X,Y)$.